# Integrating Slimbox (or Lightbox) with Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, slimbox

My personal photo gallery uses [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (for arranging the photos) and [Infinite scroll](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html) (to break down the photos' downloading time). I recently added [Slimbox2](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) (because I couldn't put Lightbox2 working for some reason). Slimbox2 works perfectly on the first page, but not on the following pages loaded by infinite scroll.

I tried using different grouping names, like `rel="lightbox-page1"` and `rel="lightbox-page2`, or no grouping at all, but none approach worked. Do I need to *refresh* Slimbox when a new page is loaded? InfiniteScroll's creator [suggests the following code](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/lightbox-compatibility-code/) `myLightbox.updateImageList();`. Makes sense? How to convert it for Slimbox? [Someone with the same problem as I do, in 2011.](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/lightbox-compatibility-code/comment-page-2/#comment-2041)

You can check my *live problem* [here](http://www.diogonunes.com/fotografia/viagem/). These are the scripts I'm currently using (you can view the page source):

```
<script>
        $(function() {

            var $container = $('#gallery');

            $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                $container.masonry({
                    itemSelector : '.box',
                    columnWidth : 1,
                    isAnimated : true
                });
            });

            $container.infinitescroll({
                navSelector : '#page-nav', // selector for the paged navigation
                nextSelector : '#page-nav a', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
                itemSelector : '.box', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
                loading : {
                    finishedMsg : 'No more pages to load.',
                    img : '/assets/img/loading.gif'
                }
            },
            // trigger Masonry as a callback
            function(newElements) {
                // hide new items while they are loading
                var $newElems = $(newElements).css({ opacity : 0 });
                // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function() {
                    // show elems now they're ready
                    $newElems.animate({ opacity : 1 });
                    $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```